# How can I determine the Cursor size in WPF?

Tags: wpf

In Windows Forms there is a Cursor.Size Property that allows you to get the size (width/height) of the cursor object. How can I determine this information in WPF?

Comment: Are you referring to the mouse cursor or the cursor you get when editing in a textbox?

Answer (score 14):

The SystemParameters class exposes [CursorWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.cursorwidth%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [CursorHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.cursorheight.aspx) properties.