# How to get size of cursor in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to get the size of rectangle of classical windows cursor.

How can I get the size of the cursor in c#?

Comment: For WPF you can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038853/how-can-i-determine-the-cursor-size-in-wpf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Cursor.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.size.aspx):

```
int cursorWidth = Cursor.Size.Width;
int cursorHeight = Cursor.Size.Height;
```

Yes, it is really that simple!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cursor size is NOT the actual cursor size. it's the image size. The cursor size is 32x32 by default but the actual visual cursor is 16x20

Comment: Correction the size is 13x20

Answer (score 2):

A small example : [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.size.aspx)

```
       if(this.Cursor != Cursors.Hand & 
         Cursor.Current == Cursors.Default)
       {
          // Draw the cursor stretched.
          Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
          Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
            new Point(10,10), new Size(cursor.Size.Width * 2, 
            cursor.Size.Height * 2));
          cursor.DrawStretched(graphics, rectangle);


      // Draw the cursor in normal size.
      rectangle.Location = new Point(
      rectangle.Width + rectangle.Location.X, 
        rectangle.Height + rectangle.Location.Y);
      rectangle.Size = cursor.Size;
      cursor.Draw(graphics, rectangle);

      // Dispose of the cursor.
      cursor.Dispose();
   }
```

Comment: That is a lot of code to show how to use `cursor.Size.Width / Height`

Comment: If I may come with a suggestion, I would either explain why you have so much code or minimize it (since it's a good example if you want to show an actual usage of the `Cursor.Size`)

Comment: Frm MSDN. Also paints the cursor, twice the size, on a form.

Comment: @ChristopheGeers Would you look at that. I didn't even scroll that far. :)

Answer (score 0):

for deep information visit MSDN 
Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.size.aspx